# What is causing my fresh Windows 7x64 install to crash?

Tags: windows-7, crash, power

My PC is a custom build with a Intel i3-7100, a Gigabyte GA-B250M-DS3H motherboard, 2x8GB GeIL EVO POTENZA DDR4 2133 RAM, and a 1TB Western Digital HD (Not sure of the exact model; it's a spare drive I used for the build.)

I keep coming home to my PC turned off, as in no power. I check the event logs and find two Kernel-Power events with ID 109 and Task Category (103). The logs say "The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition." There is nothing else out of the ordinary in the event logs. Windows starts up fine. There is no sign of random power loss. It seems like something is sending the signal to shutdown the computer, but I can't find what it is.

I installed the drivers that came from the CD to start, and then moved to the drivers from Gigabyte's website to try to remedy this. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Can anyone speculate as to what might cause this? The parts are just over a month old, and I only got Windows installed a few days ago. Do I just need to reinstall the OS?

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Have you reinstalled windows? Easiest way to debug issues and it's a fresh install so you might as well

Comment: @Ben I haven't yet. I was hoping to avoid that, as I had driver trouble when trying to install Windows 7. In the end I had to install on another computer and put that drive into the new machine. Once the OS installed it booted fine and ran fine, other than this weird issue. However, the Windows 7 installer would not recognize any drivers I tried to send to it, and wouldn't see any hard drives. I figured that was a motherboard issue. Could that be the cause of this?

Comment: Now that you say that it could definitely be a mobo issue, especially because of the random shutdowns, can you try updating the bios or reinstalling it?

Comment: @Ben I won't be able to try tonight, but I will after work tomorrow. I'll post an update then. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Come to think of it windows 7 does NOT support kaby lake CPU's and you have one. I have heard of stability issues and intel will not be making drivers for windows 7 and Kaby Lake. See if you can update it to windows 10 as that has support for Kaby Lake

Comment: @Ben Thanks. I didn't know that. I don't want to use Windows 10, so it looks like I'm off to find a version of Linux that will fit my needs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you should try windows 10 for a bit and see if you like it,  if not use Linux. Also just to amuse you: http://www.digiworthy.com/2017/01/28/windows-7-runs-on-kaby-lake-processor-igp-driver/